# Copying one video from Mac to Iphone without syncing

Tags: itunes, data-synchronization, iphone

I need to copy a video file from my Macbook to my Iphone 4. The Iphone is not synced to this Macbook but to my home computer, but I'm away from home, and I don't want to sync it to the Macbook because it will wipe everything else in the phone.

I could copy the file from the Macbook to Dropbox and download it to the Iphone from there, but my net connection here is pretty slow. Isn't there any way to copy the file from the Mac to the Iphone without syncing?

I'm using OS X 10.8.2 in the Macbook, iOS 5.1.1 on the Iphone and iTunes 10.6.3.

Comment: I'm using an app called Fileapp Pro, it gives you the possibility to add files over a WIFI connection. There are numbers of similar apps including cloud services like Dropbox, that lets you send or sync filed with your iphone.

Comment: When using Dropbox and being on the same network, your files do not need to be uploaded to the Dropbox servers to be synced. If you add a file in your Macbooks dropbox and sync the dropbox app on your iphone, it should appear, even before uploading to the drobpox server is complete. You can find this setting in your Dropbox preferences, it is called 'Over LAN sync'.

Answer (score 3):

You can use iTunes to move files directly without a sync over USB.

1. Attach your iPhone, iPod or iPad with the datacable to your the Mac.
2. In iTunes, in the top right corner, click on your device. In my case it's an iPad.

   [image]
3. Now go the the 'Apps' tab and scroll down to 'File Sharing'

   [image]
4. Choose the program you want to sent your file to

   [image]
5. Click on the 'Add' bottom in the bottom right

   [image]

The newer versions of Dropbox app supports syncing from their servers and local WiFi syncing over a LAN so you can experiment with this if you don't want to try iTunes. Apple's documentation can be found [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH12118). There are also third party tools that sync files, but for one file it's hard to justify downloading anything and just use iTunes for the task.

Answer (score 0):

The app I use to transfer any video out there into my iPhone is WALTR. It is Mac-compatible. The software is ridiculously simple. I just drag-and-drop the file and it appears in the native iOS app. The thing that I like the most is the fact that it gets the job done. I am very satisfied. 
You can find a quick 2 step guide by following the link down below:
http://softorino.com/waltr/windows-guides/transfer-video-iphone-6-without-itunes